# How can I change flutter web app preview logo?

Tags: flutter

How to change this flutter logo from my web app, although I have changed the favicon that did not change this flutter logo. A screenshot is attached for better understanding.
[image: Screen Shot]

I have successfully changed the favicon, but this logo is still showing here in google search. I want to replace this flutter logo with my own designed logo.

Answer (score 1):

Find your `index.html` in the `web` folder, and change this line:

```
<!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
```

It may take some time for Google to update the logo after you changed it.

You can speed up the updating process by submitting your updated website to Google for reindexing:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/ask-google-to-recrawl